# Can't get phpmyadmin to work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Alright, I've been following [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp) (along with others to double check) to attempt to get a working lamp stack installed, but phpmyadmin always throws an HTTP 500 server error.  PHP executes fine, it's just PHPmyadmin that will not work.

I uninstall the entire lamp stack each time and start from scratch.  I did notice step 6 which says:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

Returns the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-intl : Depends: libicu44 (>= 4.4.1-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Even if I install all of the other packages except this one and try to install phpmyadmin, it returns a 500 server error.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the comment below the tutorial [linked here](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp#comment-32151). I don't think the phpmyadmin directory is linked up with Apache2.

For what it's worth, on Ubuntu (and other Debian-based versions of Linux), you can really just type

> sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php5
>   phpmyadmin

and it will go off and install all the packages you need to get a working version of PHPMyAdmin up and running. I think that guide is having you install way too many PHP libraries that you'll likely never use. If you have issues with the above, run

> sudo apt-get --purge remove *packages from your quoted line*

From a security and simplicity perspective, you should only install the applications (packages) that you absolutely need.

Comment: Tried all that but to no avail.  Ended up re-installing the entire VM and attempting the tutorial listed here, unfortunately didn't work anything out.  Sadly I have to move on due to time constraints at this point, but I appreciate the information.

Comment: Sorry to hear, let me know if you ever want to pick it up again. It usually isn't this hard, I promise!